Custom parameters in Azure SpeechRecognizer sdk
Im currently exploring Azure Speech Services. When Iam using SpeechRecognizer.startContinuousRecognitionAsync how I can send additional parameter with client Id so on azure portal I can determine usage of SpeechService of given clients?
const token = await this.GetToken();
const speechConfig = speechsdk.SpeechConfig.fromSubscription(token.Token, token.Region);

const audioConfig = speechsdk.AudioConfig.fromDefaultMicrophoneInput();
this.speechRecognizer = new speechsdk.SpeechRecognizer(speechConfig, audioConfig);


this.speechRecognizer.startContinuousRecognitionAsync();
this.speechRecognizer.recognizing = (s, e) => 
{
    console.log(`RECOGNIZING: Text=${e.result.text}`);
    //send to azure logs token.ClientId
};

I want to see which clientId used how many seconds of SpeechService in Azure portal


Can you share your code in the question?

Its javascript on browser not nodejs that I can save to file. Custom parameters has to be saved to Azure storage not localhost.

Ok, Can you share your code?

Can you confirm once, that you are trying to save the recognized text data from speech into a .txt file in the Azure blob storage?

Recognized text data doenst contain how many seconds SpeechService used.

Sorry, I don't understand. Can you tell me clearly?

Have you tried any code? It's easy to understand if you share your code in the question.

Added my source code

Do you expect to track only how many time the service has been used by individual clients? Or, expecting to capture the duration of usage..etc?
If it's the former, could log a custom message to the log analytics along with the client ID and count the usage from that.

Its about duration of usage so I know how many seconds Ive been charged for given client. How I can send custom message to log analytics with client id then?
